# can not install mysql-server on centos 6.7 32bit . Error: need rpm?

Tags: centos, software-installation, mysql, rpm, glibc

when I try to install mysql-server on centos with this command:

`yum install mysql-server`

server replies:

```
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  11 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.mia.host-engine.com
 * epel: reflector.westga.edu
 * extras: centos.aol.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                          | 5.0 MB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
mysql-connectors-community                               | 2.4 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql56-community                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
webtatic                                                 | 3.6 kB     00:00
Package mysql-server is obsoleted by mysql-community-server, trying to install mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 instead
Resolving Dependencies
Running transaction check
Package mysql-community-server.i686 0:5.6.30-2.el7 will be installed
Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-32) = 5.6.30-2.el7 for
. 
.
.
etc . . . .
.
.
    .

Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686

Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686

Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686

Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 (mysql56-community)

Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)

Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 (mysql56-community)
  Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 (mysql56-community)
 Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 (mysql56-community)
 Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 (mysql56-community)
 Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have searched the web for `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)` but only found
`glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm` but for centos 7.2 .

I don't know if it is useful! and don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing CentOS 6 packages (`.el6`) with CentOS 7 packages (`.el7`), which is invalid. They differ a lot.

You installed `mysql56-community-release-el7.*` instead of `mysql56-community-release-el6*`, [where from](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) you get that.

Remove this wrong package source:

```
yum remove "mysql56-community-release-el7.*"
```

Install the correct one (as you installed the above mentioned before) and then it should work for you.

---

Find `mysql-56-community` in your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and disable that by setting `enable=0` inside, if you don't know what is that doing there.

Comment: Than you for the answer. I have tried: `yum remove "mysql56-community-release-el7.*"`   but it gives me : `No Packages marked for removal`.    and tried :  `yum remove "mysql-community-libs-5.6.30-2.el7.i686"` .  and it gives me: `Package(s) mysql-community-libs-5.6.30-2.el7.i686 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal`

Comment: Also tried : `yum clean all`. but did not work

Comment: So first find out where does `mysql56-community` repository come from.  That was just a guess. It should be in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and somebody had to install it.

Comment: yes its there! `mysql-community.repo` and `mysql-community-source.repo`  how can I get rid of it.

Comment: First possibility is to disable them (there is a row `enable=1`, you can write there `enable=0`), so it will not be used. If you don't know how did it get there, just do that. It should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you very much! my problem solved. you saved me hours!!