# Mysql yum install how to get right dependencies Centos 6.9

Tags: centos, yum, mysql

I'm trying to get MySql 5.7 installed on a Centos 6.9 system. I've been following instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/):

I've downloaded this rpm:

```
mysql57-community-release-el6.rpm
```

and installed it with this command:

```
rpm -Uvh mysql57-community-release-el6.rpm
```

But, at this point, it's not really installed. This command:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

shows this:

```
mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch
```

And, if I type "mysql", nothing happens. I think there are dependencies that need to be downloaded.

If I edit this file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo,`

I see this

```
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

(among others). I manually changed the 7 to 6.

Finally, when I type this:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

I get this result:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.22-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.22-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.22-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.22-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.22-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
```

So, it's somehow retaining the e7 dependencies, possibly from a previous install gone wrong. How do I get it to download the correct dependencies?

edit: Per the suggest duplicate, I tried:

```
yum remove "mysql56-community-release-el7.*"
```

I also removed the mysql package by this:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

and got response:

```
Removed:
  mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el6-
```

But when I try a re-install, it comes up with the same message.

Also, per the comments from the OP, I previously edited

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo
```

to only choose the correct edition, but the install is still trying to load the wrong dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can not install mysql-server on centos 6.7 32bit . Error: need rpm?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280385/can-not-install-mysql-server-on-centos-6-7-32bit-error-need-rpm)

Comment: I don’t see an answer to this question in the proposed duplicate. The dupe mixed 6 with 7, which I don’t see here.